# MongoDB returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have this simple program that is storing in MongoDB 3 variables - **X** , **Y** and **MESSAGE** in collection named **coordinates**. Now I need to find and use 10 latest entries from there. I've found that I can do that with `collection.find({}).skip(collection.count() - 10)`and then convert it array with `.toArray()`. My full code line looks like this

```
var notesArray=collection.find({}).skip(collection.count() - 10).toArray;
    if (notesArray.length > 0) { console.log(notesArray[0]); }
```

and in console it shows 'undefined'. What I need to do, is to get an array of **X**, array of **Y**, and array of **MESSAGE** , all of them containing 10 latest entries? I will need to use these 10 x,y and messages in other functions later. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

After putting `collection.find().limit(3).toArray(function(err, docs) { console.log(docs); })` into code, I'm getting 3 first records from the database like this

> [ { _id: 5878f25df5cfe2d8002fdc72,
>        x: 450,
>        y: 265,
>        message: 'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQq' },
>
> { _id: 5878f263f5cfe2d8002fdc73,
>        x: 1146,
>        y: 245,
>        message: 'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQq' },
>
> { _id: 5878f267f5cfe2d8002fdc74,
>        x: 216,
>        y: 175,
>        message: 'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQq QQQQ' } ]

I think I need to do it like this `collection.find().skip(collection.count() - 10).toArray(function(err, docs) { console.log(docs); })` but then I get error **`TypeError: callback is not a function`**

**EDIT2:**

Everything was fixed by changing uppercase letters to lowercase.

Comment: call to find() is asynchronous, so you do not get data like this. Either you need to use Promises or you can use callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework to get the desired results. The following example demonstrates how you can run the **[`aggregate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#aggregate)** pipeline within nodejs:

```
// Correctly call the aggregation framework using a pipeline in an Array.
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    // Create a collection
    var collection = db.collection('coordinates');

    // Execute aggregate, notice the pipeline is expressed as an Array
    collection.aggregate([
        { "$sort": { "_id": -1 } },
        { "$limit": 10 },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": null,
                "x": { "$push": "$x" },
                "y": { "$push": "$y" },
                "message": { "$push": "$message" }
            }
        }
    ], function(err, notesArray) {
        console.log('X: ', notesArray[0].x);
        console.log('Y: ', notesArray[0].y);
        console.log('MESSAGE: ', notesArray[0].message);

        var firstX = notesArray[0].x[0];
        console.log(firstX);

        console.log(notesArray);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

---

The above aggregate operation first sorts the documents in the collection by the `_id` field using the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline operator. Since sorting on an `_id` field that stores **[`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid)** values is roughly equivalent to sorting by creation time, you 
are able to get the latest documents if the MongoDB driver automatically generates an **[`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid)** for the `_id` field on document creation. Otherwise if the `_id` is not an **[`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid)** , you will need to sort on a timestamp field that denotes
the datetime the document was created in order to determine the last n documents in a query.

The next step entails selecting the top 10 documents from the sorted list. This is made possible with the **[`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit)** operator.

Finally, you group all the documents and create data lists for each field through the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline. The **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** accumulator operator makes it possible to create an array of values from the group on a specified field. The _id field in **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** stage is mandatory; however, you can specify an `_id` value of null to calculate accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole as above.

The final result would be an array with just a single document which will have an `_id` of `null` and the three fields i.e. an array of `X`, array of `Y`, and array of `MESSAGE`, all of them containing 10 latest entries:

```
notesArray = [
    {
        "_id": null,
        "X": [/* last 10 x values */],
        "Y": [/* last 10 y values */],
        "MESSAGE": [/* last 10 MESSAGE values */]
    }
]
```

Comment: I've tried to implement your code, but now I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` error. Any clues how to fix that?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the results you get when you run `collection.find().limit(3).toArray(function(err, docs) { console.log(docs); })`?

Comment: Updated, notice that I'm getting first 3, but not the last 3.

Comment: I think I need to do it like this `collection.find().skip(collection.count() - 10).toArray(function(err, docs) { console.log(docs); })` but then I get error **TypeError: callback is not a function**

Comment: I think I see why you are getting the error, it's because of the field names. In my answer the fields x, y and message are all in CAPITALS, just as you specified in your [original question revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41638499/1). Now that you have shown the sample documents in your collection, the names are not in capitals. Can you confirm that please? If that's the case then change the group part `"X": { "$push": "$x" },
                "Y": { "$push": "$y" },
                "MESSAGE": { "$push": "$message" }`

Comment: You don't need to do `collection.find().skip(collection.count() - 10).toArray(function(err, docs) { console.log(docs); })`, use the aggregation pipeline as suggested in the answer, that way is more efficient than to make two calls to the server i.e. 1) `collection.find()` and 2) `collection.count()`, besides the calls should be async.

Comment: I would suggest you create a new question and do not modify your original one to accommodate a new question since that's not encouraged here (as discussed in [**this meta thread**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/)).

Comment: Thank you, I've solved all my problems, I will return question to its original theme.

Answer (score 0):

You need a callback there.

```
collection
    .find()
    .limit(10)
    .toArray(function(err, notesArray) {
        if (notesArray.length > 0)
            console.log(notesArray[0]);
    });
```

More information in [MongoDB docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html#time-to-query).

**EDIT** (*To include db connection and collection name*)

Here is the full code that you will require:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Change the database URL and database name as per your requirement
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/database_name", function(err, db) {

    if(err) return console.dir(err);

    var collection = db.collection('coordinates');

    collection
        .find()
        .limit(10)
        .toArray(function(err, notesArray) {
            if (notesArray.length > 0)
                console.log(notesArray[0]);
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. When I add this, it now shows `TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null`. Error occours on  `var collection = db.collection("coordinates");` How to fix this? Also, when I will get the array I need, how to use it later? Thank you very much.

Comment: @odinas1212 The problem is you want latest 10 entries but you do not have any date/time field to determine which are the latest entries. Anyways, I have edited my answer to limit the returned data to 10 records (they may not be latest).

Comment: Thank you again @SantanuBiswas, something started to work. After putting that code, I'm now getting `{ _id: 5878f25df5cfe2d8002fdc72,
  x: 450,
  y: 265,
  message: 'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQq' }` in my console. But only one entry, not 10 of them. About latest 10 entries, I thought `.skip(collection.count() - 10)` is supposed to take care of that, but you didn't use it in your code? Also, to make as less comments as possible, lets imagine everything is working already, and I'm receiving 10 latest entries. How do I access (use) lets say 1st **X** ? Thank you again.

Comment: @odinas1212  **(a)** `collection.count() - 10` will not work because `collection` is not defined at the time of making that function call. **(b)** Assuming that you have a `_id` (ObjectId) in your data records, you can do a descending sort by `_id` before retrieving the first 10 documents.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Mongo return promise you have to call the then function to access the data.

```
var url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/my_db_name';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
 if(!err){
   var collection = db.collection('coordinates');
   collection.find({},{_id : 0}, {limit : 10}).toArray().then(function(results){
    console.log(results);
   }).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
   });
 }
})
```

Comment: Hello, after using this I'm getting `node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\cursor.js:159 throw new Error('callback is mandatory'); ^ Error: callback is mandatory` Any ideas ?

Comment: I think here `Error: callback is mandatory at Cursor.toArray (node_modules\mongodb\lib \mongodb\cursor.js:159:11) at SocketNamespace.<anonymous> \server.js:7 2:45)`

Comment: That code is perfectly running in my pc. Anyway then u can use this as well `collection.find({},{_id : 0}, {limit : 10}).toArray(function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
   })`